# How to Bind child Gridview control which is used inside template field of Parent Gridview Control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I am working in a project and my Requirement is such that i need to used a Gridview Control as a Templatefield for another Gridview Control and Bind a Generic List to it Dynamically Before Rendering it to User. Is there any way to Bind Child Gridview (Inside Templatefield)?

Lets say:
Parent Gridview: PGridview
Child Gridview: CGridview

I am Really Confused how the PGridView.Databind() will work in this case.

which GridView to bind First and how?

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this issue , please verify that on which field relationship are maintain between 
Parent Gridview: PGridview and Child Gridview: CGridview

Comment: hi Vishal,thanks for the Reply.i am binding the Parent Gridview to a Datatable,while trying to bind the Child Gridview to an Independent List.But I am unable to access Templatefiled CGridView in the code behind by FindControl method.I Want to know how can i assign values to a Gridview Templatefields Dynamically or in CodeBehind,before Rendering it to user. The CGridview has no relationship with the datatable that i am binding to the PGridview.